# Evaluate a function in several points

Tags: wolframalpha

How can I evaluate a function in several points, when I have a function like `f(x) = x^2` and I would like to compute `f(10) - f(9)`?
I know that I can evaluate this function in each point by `evaluate x^2 at x=10`, is it possible to evaluate this function in several points?

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
evaluate x^2 at x in {9,10}
```

Comment: What if I have something more complex like `f(10)^2-f(9)^1.5`? How do I get this result without evaluating a function at each point?